# Is there any app to copy Ctrl+C any text from Desktop (Windows) and paste Ctrl+V in iphone at anywhere?

Tags: iphone

Is there any app to copy Ctrl+C any text from Desktop (Windows) and paste Ctrl+V in iphone at anywhere; at editor, address bar in safai and wheneever we have keyboard on and we can paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Pastefire](http://pastefire.com/)? It is a little more constrained than any box, but it works.

Comment: nice!  hadn't heard of this one.

Comment: :) glad to share.

Comment: Nice thing it [has always been free, so far](http://appshopper.com/productivity/pastefire).

Comment: No longer free. Does it work?